# TypeError: Expected throat size to be a number but got undefined

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs, automated-tests, jest-circus

I am trying to use the jest-circus runner with jest. Without the runner the tests execute correctly but as soon as i add the line:

```
  'testRunner': 'jest-circus/runner',
```

to my jest config. I see the following error:

```
 FAIL  migration.test.js
 ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Expected throat size to be a number but got undefined

  at throat (node_modules/throat/index.js:34:13)
  at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports (node_modules/throat/index.js:76:12)
```

What does this error mean? am i missing something in the config ?

Here is my full config:

```html
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  'verbose': true,
  'globalSetup': './tests/setup.js',
  'globalTeardown': './tests/teardown.js',
  'testEnvironment': './CustomNodeEnvironment.js',
  'setupTestFrameworkScriptFile': './jest.setup.js',
  'testMatch': [ '**/?(*.)test.js?(x)' ],
  'testRunner': 'jest-circus/runner',
  'reporters': ['default', 'jest-junit', ['jest-junit', {'configValue': true, 'output': '/tmp/junit.xml'}]]
};
```

Comment: Candidate for the best error message ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a version compatibility issue.

Using jest version 23 with jest-circus 24 will give you that error. So just upgrade jest to version 24 and it will work fine.